# $a+b=x$ and $ab=x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if it is known which two numbers, $a$ and $b$, can both add and multiply to equal any given number, $x$?  To give a few examples:

If I said which two numbers both add and multiply to equal $4$, then:

$2+2=4$ and $2\cdot2=4$

In this case, $a$ and $b$ are the same, which is an important quality to keep.  But what if I asked which two numbers can both add and multiply to equal $\pi$?  How about $\sqrt3$ or some imaginary number?  Can you satisfy the relationship:

$a+b=x=ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively the same?

Comment: $ab=a+b\iff a=\frac b{b-1}$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917440/ab-ab-a-b-if-a-and-b-are-positive-integers).

Comment: This is also a solution, but when you use 5 as x, or b as you have labeled it, you get 6.25... using 5 should have returned 5

Comment: Actually, when you used 6.25 it should have returned the two numbers 1.25 and 5 .  When is 6.25+6.25=6.25 AND 6.25×6.25=6.25?  Obviously never, but what transform could you do to the two numbers on the left hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for some $y$,
\begin{align}
(y-a)(y-b) &= y^2-ay - by +ab \\
&= y^2 -(a+b)y+ab \\
&= y^2-xy+x \\
\end{align}
So  solutions to $y^2-xy+x = 0 \iff$
$$y = \frac{1}{2}\left(x \pm \sqrt{x^2-4x}\right)$$ 
and $(a, b)$ are the solutions to this.

Answer (score 1):

You already wrote an equation to solve:

$$a+b=ab \implies ab-a-b+1=1 \implies (a-1)(b-1)=1 \implies a= \frac{1}{b-1}+1$$

So given some $b$ (with or without any constraints), you can calculate $a=\frac{1}{b-1} +1=\frac{b}{b-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is $x=a=b=0$. Besides this, let $\alpha=\dfrac1a,\beta:=\dfrac1b$.

We have

$$a+b=ab\iff\alpha+\beta=1$$

and

$$\alpha(1-\alpha)=\frac1x$$

or

$$\alpha,\beta=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{\dfrac14-\dfrac1x}}2$$

Comment: Interesting result, but using that a×b != a+b

Comment: @ßrianGolden: can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Those two numbers are roots of the quadratic equation $t^2-xt+x=0$.